# How to return the tuple value if condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, tuples

The objective is to return the first item (int) if the second item of the tuple contain the string `AUTO`.

The expected is `[23,24,25]` for a given list_of_tuples as below.

```
list_of_tuples = (
(0, ()), (1, ()), (2, ()), (3, ()), (4, ()), (5, ()), (6, ()), (7, ()), (8, ()), (9, ()), (10, ()), (11, ()), (12, ()),
(13, ()), (14, ()), (15, ()), (16, ()), (17, ()), (18, ()), (19, ()), (20, ()), (21, ()), (22, ()),
(23, ('AUTO',)), (24, ('AUTO',)), (25, ('AUTO',)))
```

I tried something like below, but it give me empty `list`.

```
index_list = [ind for ind, (a, _) in enumerate (list_of_tuples) if a == 'AUTO']
```

Comment: @superbrain, it just does not return what author wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. It's easiest to access the second element of each tuple in your list comprehension:

```
[x[0] for x in list_of_tuples if "AUTO" in x[1]]
```

Output:

```
[23, 24, 25]
```